# Why do we assume that $\varepsilon< 1$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm proving that $1$ is a boundary point of the interval $A = [1,3)$. The following is from typed class notes:

> The number $1$ is a boundary point of $[1,3)$, since for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $N(1,\varepsilon)$ contains points in $A$, like $1$, and points not in $A$, like the average of $1$ and $1- \varepsilon$, assuming that $\epsilon < 1$.

Why do we assume that $\epsilon < 1$? I've been drawing several open intervals centered at $1$, and I don't see why we have that constraint.

Comment: Please use \varepsilon (better typography) consistently instead of \epsilon and \varepsilon at the same time.

Comment: I suppose they wanted $1-\varepsilon$ to be a positive number. It's still a true statement without it.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought that I was missing something important.